# How to align inline-block icons with labels?

Tags: html, image, icons, alignment

I am trying to horizontally align labeled icons but have been having trouble like in the snipped below. For some reason, the icons are refusing to align. I made sure there wasn't white space on the image file that was causing this, so I am not sure why it is happening. In addition, what I have now is causing a subsequent p-tag to display inline-block. Any advice is appreciated!

```html
<div style='float:left'><div><img src='https://www.wgeil.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/balcony.png' width='50px'></div><span>The First Label</span></div></div>

<div style='float:left'><div><img src='https://www.wgeil.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pet-friendly.png' width='50px'></div><span>The Second Label</span></div></div>

<p>Some text that needs to start on a new line..</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use css `inline-block`. Use any other css class to fine tune the margin between the icons as you wish.

```html
<div style='display: inline-block;'><div><img src='https://www.wgeil.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/balcony.png' width='50px'></div><span>The First Label</span></div></div>

<div style='display: inline-block;'><div><img src='https://www.wgeil.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pet-friendly.png' width='50px'></div><span>The Second Label</span></div></div>

<p>Some text that needs to start on a new line..</p>
```